# Java: What type to use for sorted map with primitive double as key?

Tags: java, collections, primitive-types

I basically reviewed few open source libraries providing primitive collections types but can't find the exact thing I need.

Here are my requirements:

1. Primitive double as a key
2. Object as value, or (even better) parametrized by value type
3. Sorted - after each insertion sorts automatically
4. Sorting should be customizable - I might need my own sorting on doubles

Advise, please. Performance matters but let's not hollywar here on which favorite lib is faster.

PS: Please, do not ask why i need primitive double as  a key.

Thank you for your advises!

Comment: Just use `Double`. Java will auto box and auto unbox for you, so it will *feel* like you've got a primitive key type. Performance should not be a problem: It is highly unlikely that using `Double` will matter.

Comment: @delnan The wrapper classes are fast and lightweight. You would have to have 100's of millions of entries to notice memory problems. This is a case of "early optimization" - and frankly a real time waster,

Comment: @Bohemian This is exactly what I don't want to do. There are many reasons. Performance should not be a problem but it is a problem, garbage collections because of extra garbage also a problem. Finally if it would be so easy there would be no trove and pcj libraries written.

Comment: If he needs primitives to save memory, is guava a good option?

Comment: @Leo: no. Guava doesn't have primitive collections.

Comment: @vladimir Post that code and we can help! Also, if you know about trove and pcj it sounds like you have a [cart before the horse](http://thecryptojournalist.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/putting-the-cart-before-the-horse.gif); but maybe [HPCC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html) can help.

Comment: @JBNizet this is a problem about this question. If we could at least know why he needs primitives, it would be easier to decide.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I can't really post the code. Though I can describe it. There are messages on a data feed which are deserialized in pooled objects which have double members. There's huge amount of messages every second. I need to store collection of objects (not from transport) associated with double values in a sorted way - this is how I have to expose them. If I use autoboxing it produces GCs which are causing server lugging. Transport library doesn't generate any garbage. So I see that my code is memmory and performance bottleneck.

Comment: ...and you profiled the above, such that you're 100% certain that the GC events are being triggered primarily by autoboxing/autounboxing?

Comment: @vladimir [disruptor](http://mechanitis.blogspot.com/2011/06/dissecting-disruptor-whats-so-special.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks, I'm familiar with Disruptor pattern, will think how to apply it here.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I used profiler. There's nothing much else happening in the code. Why asking? Isn't it something simple to happen? Though I have to say it took some of my time to debug this.

Comment: It's just that this smells like a micro optimization.  If you've profiled it and are certain that this is your bottleneck, then more power to you.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I understand that it smells like micro optimization. I hate it myself and usually the first one in the project who against such things. I spent a week trying to find some other design. I already tested trove (without sorting though) and it helped - just curious if there's some library providing sorting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/), [colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) or [apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-primitives/userguide.html). From first glance it doesn't appear that they have built in auto-sorting (and chances are it's probably be pretty slim pickings to find one since auto-sorting and efficiency aren't usually closely related :-)) but that shouldn't be too hard for you to implement on top of their classes.

[Here's](http://b010.blogspot.com/2009/05/speed-comparison-of-1-javas-built-in.html) a blog post showing the comparison between a couple primitive collection wrappers and java.util

Comment: The trove has the closest types to waht I need, but you are right - there's no sorting there. I was hoping that there's some ready to use library...

Comment: Unfortunately, those two requirements are at odds with each other :-\

Comment: But, java 7's Arrays.sort() uses Timsort (http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) which is just about as fast as it gets right now. You could also use Collections.sort() which would provide you with consistent O(nlogn) performance.